# Hyperledger -- Contract instantiation issue

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to instantiate the java contact in Commercial Paper Tutorial and get the following error in the monitor.

There is no issue while installing the chain code.

Command run: 
docker exec cliMagnetoCorp peer chaincode instantiate -n papercontract -v 0 -l java -c '{"Args":["org.papernet.commercialpaper:instantiate"]}' -C mychannel -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member')"

Error:

peer0.org1.example.com|2019-12-19 00:10:10.220 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 045 [mychannel][7cd11866] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 1

Please help on what i should do to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Fixed the issue. 
Changed the build.gradle entry for fabric-chaincode-shim version from 1.4.2 to 1.4.4

compile group: 'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java', name: 'fabric-chaincode-shim', version: '1.4.4'